# Формирование адреса

Tags: delphi, сеть, сокеты

Использую Delphi XE.
Есть вот такой код

```
function ResolveAddress(Address: String): TInAddr;
var
  Host: PHostEnt;
begin
  Result.S_addr := inet_addr(PChar(Address));
  if Result.S_addr = INADDR_NONE then
  begin
    Host := gethostbyname(PChar(Address));
    if Host <> nil then
      Result := PInAddr(Host.h_addr_list^)^;
  end;
end;
```

Если вызываю `ResolveAddress('localhost')` ,  то `inet_addr` в функции выше возвращает -1
а если написать так

```
function ResolveAddress(Address: String): TInAddr;
var
  Host: PHostEnt;
begin
  Result.S_addr := inet_addr('localhost');
  if Result.S_addr = INADDR_NONE then
  begin
    Host := gethostbyname(PChar(Address));
    if Host <> nil then
      Result := PInAddr(Host.h_addr_list^)^;
  end;
end;
```

То все нормально.

Делал вот так `inet_addr(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(Address)))`, но результат тот же.

Comment: Такое же преобразование (к `PAnsiChar`) стоит провести и для `GetHostByName`, насколько я вижу...

Comment: до `GetHostByName` не доходит `inet_addr(PChar(Address))` ранее возвращает - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функцию нужно объявить вот так:

```
function ResolveAddress(const Address: AnsiString): TInAddr;
```

и все `PChar` заменить на `PAnsiChar`:

```
Result.S_addr := inet_addr(PAnsiChar(Address));
...
Host := gethostbyname(PAnsiChar(Address));
```

Далее, функция `inet_addr` воспринимает только IP адреса в формате `x.x.x.x` и она не может работать со строкой вида `localhost` by design. Для этого предназначена функция `gethostbyname`.

Поэтому, если вы передаёте на вход вашей `ResolveAddress` строку `localhost`, то `inet_addr` вполне закономерно работать не будет и код войдёт в ветку с получением адреса по имени, через `gethostbyname`. Это нормальное поведение вашей функции.

Answer (score 0):

Из рабочего проекта:

```
function ValidateIP(const IP: AnsiString): TInAddr;
begin
  Result := TInAddr(inet_addr(PAnsiChar(@IP[1])));
  if DWORD(Result) = INADDR_NONE then
    raise EArgumentException.CreateFmt('IP adress ''%s'' is not valid!', [string(IP)]);
end;
```

Можно еще входной параметр проверить на Length > 0.